# How can we integrate REST api with tally?

Tags: java, rest, integration, tally

I want to integrate Tally ERP application with the REST webservices. When any action performed in Tally the Entry of the Data should be reflect on the REST database.

How can a purchase order created in tally Transferred to Remote Database?

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate with tally using XML. Send a request in the correct xml format, receive the response in xml. Then deserialize into your object type. And then use that to transfer to remote database.

For comms with Tally see - http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/tally/td9/Tally.ERP9_Integration_Capabilities.pdf